# htaccess rewrite (folders and file in folder redirect)

Tags: .htaccess

I have some folders and file in the folders, I would like to do a 301 redirect to PHP files
I am wanting:

/folder/ > /file.php

/folder/index.html > /file.php

I have tried doing a google but can't find what I am looking for.

Can anyone help

Comment: That's a general idea, good, but please be more specific and try to add examples of URLs to redirect and redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked it out, this is what I am using and it works for me

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/(.*)$ /file.php
```